# How to run java files that I have mentioned in my testng xml?

Tags: java, ant, testng

I have a testng.xml file and a build.xml file. I want to know how can we write code in build.xml file which can run all java files that I have mentioned in my testng.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `testng` task and call it.

More details are in [the doc](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html)

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="testng.jar"/>


<testng classpathref="run.cp"
        outputDir="${testng.report.dir}"
        sourcedir="${test.src.dir}"
        haltOnfailure="true">

   <xmlfileset dir="${test14.dir}" includes="testng.xml"/>
</testng>
```

Comment: @Santosh Kumar Did my answer solve your problem. If yes you can accept it, in this case people will be more motivated to help you